# How does QTcpSocket write data to client?

Tags: qt, qtcpsocket

I wanna make a simple Qt app which can perform task like image below:

[image]

I have learnt Fortune Server examples and actually I want this app is just like the combination of Fortune Server and Fortune Client.

**dialog.cpp**

```
void Dialog::on_btnListen_clicked(bool checked)
{
    if(checked)
    {
        listener = new ServerSock(this);
        if(!listener->listen(QHostAddress::LocalHost,ui->boxPort->value()))
        {
            QMessageBox::critical(this,tr("Error"),tr("Cannot listen: %1").arg(listener->errorString()));
            ui->btnListen->setChecked(false);
            return;
        }
        else
        {
            qDebug() << "Server is listening to port" << listener->serverPort();
            ui->btnListen->setText(tr("Listening"));
            this->setWindowTitle(tr("Listening and Running"));
        }
    }
    else
    {
        listener->close();
        listener->deleteLater();

        ui->tmbListen->setText(tr("Listen again"));
        this->setWindowTitle(tr("Taking a rest"));
    }
}
```

**serversock.cpp**:

```
#include "serversock.h"

ServerSock::ServerSock(QObject *parent) :
    QTcpServer(parent)
{
}

void ServerSock::incomingConnection(int descriptor)
{
    thread = new Threading(descriptor,this);
    connect(thread,SIGNAL(finished()),thread,SLOT(deleteLater()));
    thread->start();
}
```

**threading.cpp**:

```
#include "threading.h"

Threading::Threading(int descriptor, QObject *parent) :
    QThread(parent)
{
    this->descriptorSocket = descriptor;
}

void Threading::run()
{
    qDebug() << "Thread is started...";
    socketThread = new QTcpSocket();
    if(!socketThread->setSocketDescriptor(this->descriptorSocket))
    {
        emit error(socketThread->error());
        return;
    }

    connect(socketThread,SIGNAL(readyRead()),this,SLOT(readyToRead()),Qt::DirectConnection);
    connect(socketThread,SIGNAL(disconnected()),this,SLOT(unconnected()),Qt::DirectConnection);
    qDebug() << descriptorSocket << "Connected";
    exec(); //loop
}

void Threading::readyToRead()
{
    QByteArray data = socketThread->readAll();

    socketOut = new QTcpSocket();
    socketOut->connectToHost("192.168.0.1",8080);
    if(socketOut->waitForConnected(5000))
    {

        QByteArray query("GET http:// mysite. com/page HTTP/1.1\r\nHost: anothersite.com\r\r\r\n" + data); //example
        socketOut->write(query);
        socketOut->write("\r\r\r\n");
        socketOut->waitForBytesWritten(1000);
        socketOut->waitForReadyRead(3000);

        outPut = socketOut->readAll();
        if(socketOut->error() != socketOut->UnknownSocketError)
        {
            qDebug() << socketOut->errorString();
            socketOut->disconnectFromHost();

            this->quit();
            socketThread->abort();
        }
        else
        {
        socketOut->close();
        }
    }
    else
    {
        qDebug() << "Cannot connected";
    }

    if(!outPut.isNull())
        socketThread->write(outPut); 

    qDebug() << descriptorSocket << " Data in: " << data;

void Threading::unconnected()
{
    qDebug() << "Disconnected";
    socketThread->abort();
    exit(0);
    deleteLater();
}
```

The problem is that I don't know how to return data from remote host to the local client, like the image below:

[image]

it sends request, but there is no response. How to accomplish this?

Comment: First: I think there is a typo in your code (Data should be lowercase).

Second: Obviously, you could not connect to 192.168.0.1 ("Cannot connect" debug message). Therefore you did not fetch any data into "outPut" and subsequently did not write to the client socket.

-> The question should be now : "Why do you cannot connect to the ?WAS? (don't know the server type) server"?

EDIT: moved to comments.

Comment: What Data did you mean? I think I have change all 'data' to lowercase.  Actually, 192.168.0.1 is just an example, and I don't have LAN. So, does it have to connected to host first, to obtain any data to be passed to outPut?

Comment: Ok ... please let me get this straight: You have a server and some clients. The server waits until a clients connects. If a client connects the server will try to fetch some data from another server (Web), process the data and sends this chunk back to the client. Am i right? Your question was: How do you send the data back to the client. Since you have an open socket for the client you can easily send data back (you already wrote the code with `if(!outPut.isNull()) socketThread->write(outPut);`). The problem is here, that you did not connect with the web server (see debug msg).

Comment: Just a piece of advice: If you are targeting Windows OS you must be really carful using blocked actions with sockets since the Qt implementation is buggy (i do not have the bug report at hand - so just google it). The bug is still present in 5.2 and i had to write my own interface using winsocks. So be really carful to use all the waitFor... methods.

Comment: Yes, you're right. Okay, you explain it properly. And I'm targetting the app for just Linux

Comment: @DominikSelzer I find that using blocking calls (`waitForXxx` or `exec`) is a recipe for disaster. It makes it much harder to test the code, since you allow reentrancy where otherwise there would be none. The only place left in Qt where you're forced to reenter the event loop like that is `QDrag`.

Comment: @Kuba Generally you are right and i typically do not use blocking calls. But i used to work on a Qt RServe interface and using blocking calls for rather complicated protocols is ofter more straight forward than handling lots of protocol states when using non-blocked calls. Generally speaking: Everything that may block the main event loop is a pretty ugly thing.